# Why does JSP duplicate records on the client-side when refreshed?

Tags: jsp

My JSP page duplicates the record it displays on the client-side when refreshed. I tried another project with the same process but it works fine. Here is the screenshot of the page. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcMrS.png)

Here is my code in welcome-file (Controller)

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Todo> todos = null;
    try {
        todos = todoDaoImpl.getTodos();
        request.setAttribute("todo_list", todos);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("views/list-todo.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warning("Error in list todo");
    }
}
```

JSP code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <caption>Your Todos are:</caption>
  <tr>
    <th id="desc">Description</th>
    <th id="category">Category</th>
    <th id="action">Action</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${todo_list}" var="todo">
      <tr>
        <td>${todo.todos}</td>
        <td>${todo.category}</td>
        <td><a href="${loadTodoLink}" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger" href="${deleteLink}" onclick="if(!(confirm('Do you want to delete this?'))) return false">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

DAO code

```
List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public List < Todo > getTodos() throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT * from todo";

    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String todo = rs.getString("todo");
            String category = rs.getString("category");

            todos.add(new Todo(id, todo, category));
        }
        return todos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your DAO Code, you have this: `todos.add(new Todo(id, todo, category));`.

Each time you hit the `getTodos()` method you are adding to the list.

Either have the `todos` list be part of your method (as opposed to being declared as a global variable) or else, clear it in the `getTodos()` method before you fill it up.